# Can we have j/k style (like Gmail) scrolling through posts?

Tags: feature-request

Can we have j/k style (like Gmail) scrolling through posts, or is it already possible?

Often you don't want to scroll with the mouse, and using the down arrow or spacebar is just not enough.

You might have noticed that Facebook has just implemented (and rolled out) such a feature to browse through the posts on a page.

Answer (score 6):

There's a userscript [that adds keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one) to Stack Exchange sites. Download it here:

> https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-keyboard-shortcuts/raw/tip/sekeys.updating.user.js

It allows you to scroll through posts with <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>, as well as paginate with <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (next page) and <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (previous page).

There are other options for editing, commenting, flagging, going to different sections, et cetera.

Comment: thanks a lot. 
But, what if it is enabled by default ?
also this custom JS scripts cannot be used with Chrome as add-on. Don't know about Firefox, though.

Comment: It can be used within Chrome. Just download the `.user.js` file, then in Chrome go to `chrome://extensions` and drag the file onto the page. It'll then install. I don't know why they haven't enabled it by default.

Comment: Probably because its still too buggy (or was when I tried it)

Comment: @Daniel Hm. Works pretty well for me, and I've been using it for months. But there might be incompatibilities with some browers, I don't know.

Comment: @slhck [It took me no time at all to find a bug when I used it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141590).